# Why iterating over ArrayIterator ending with endless loop?

Tags: php, infinite-loop, arrayiterator

Array in my code is quite big so I pasting it in pastebin. http://pastebin.com/6tviT2Xj

I don't understand why I am getting endless loop

Logic of this script is:

```
$it = new ArrayIterator($options);
while($it->valid()) {
    print $it->key();
    print $it->current();
}
```

Comment: Not using `foreach` when using iterators seems so like PHP3... ;)

Comment: Yeah, but I must know about next element.

Comment: Anyway shame that I forget about next() :P

Comment: You should use foreach. Better performance than while. Less error prone, like you demonstrated.

Comment: @Sven - Do you have any benchmarks for the better performance you claim?

Comment: @Sven you can't get next Array element using foreach (probably) and I don't care about performance. It just must work

Comment: http://www.phpbench.com/ claims foreach is 5 times faster than while when reading a native array. But I do not believe benchmarks of others, so do your own. :)

Comment: @Sven anyway thanks for this performance info ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you never move in you iterator ([with ArrayIterator::next()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayiterator.next.php)).

```
while ($it->valid()) {
    ...
    $it->next();
}
```

Comment: Just Curios .. did you test this code ??? .. You would know it has errors  if you did

Comment: @Baba - No, I just added the `$it->next()` -- because that's the cause of the problem. What errors do you mean?

Comment: Just edited your code with proper formatting .. you can see the diffence

Answer (score 3):

you should use  `$it->next();` else you will cicle over the same key eternally

Answer (score 2):

you're iterating over current element, you need to do `$it->next();` to point/go to the next element

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is not using `$it->next();` in your but that still many not give you the desired output because If you run `print $it->current();` it would only return `Array` since you can not output array information with `print`.

You should be using `RecursiveArrayIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator` since you are dealing with multidimensional array

To get all values try :

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($options));
foreach ( $it as $key => $val ) {
    echo $key . ":" . $val . "\n";
}
```

See full demo : http://codepad.viper-7.com/UqF18q